# What's the correct way to write this jquery attr code? (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this in my theme's function file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ajax-loader").attr("src","<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif");
});
```

However, when it prints, the src prints as `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif`, that is showing the php code instead of showing my template url. What would be the correct way to write this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this in a `.js` file? If so, you can't place WordPress template tags inside because `.js` files are not processed by PHP.

You can either include your code inline within `header.php` using `<script>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ajax-loader").attr("src","<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif");
});
</script>
```

Or change the extension of your JavaScript file from `.js` to `.php`, and add this line at the very top:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/javascript'); ?>
```

That tells the server to treat this as a JavaScript file, although it'll be processed by PHP.

In any case, you're using `.attr()` correctly.